# jBoss Portal deployment

Tags: jboss-portal

I am new in jBoss and Portal

I download the jBoss Tools for Eclipse and go through the document to create Java Portlet http://docs.jboss.org/tools/3.1.0.GA/en/jboss_portal_tools_ref_guide/html/portlet_tools_tasks.html#deploying_to_portal

When I run the application in server and go to http://localhost:8080/portal/portal/default/default/

I cannot see my portlet, any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default URL for JBoss is http://localhost:8080/portal.